# Order by last name in angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to sort the list of contacts by its **LAST NAME** with name list under each Alphabet. It can be done easily in jquery and angular-1 but how do I implement the logic in Angular2/Ionic V2?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: There is no inbuilt sorting in Angular 2 like Angular 1, Check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103733/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-angular2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381505/pipes-angular-2-sort-array-of-objects

Comment: see this link : http://www.fueltravel.com/blog/migrating-from-angular-1-to-2-part-1-pipes/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a pipe, and sort for the value you need.

See this sample:

```
import { Pipe } from "angular2/core";
import {Todo} from './todo';

@Pipe({
  name: "sort"
})
export class TodosSortPipe {
  transform(array: Array<Todo>, args: string): Array<Todo> {
    // Do YOUR LOGIC HERE, like this code below

    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a < b) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
}
```

and then use it like:

```
*ngFor="let item of array | sort"
```

Source:

> [Angular 2 OrderBy Pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158817/angular-2-orderby-pipe)

Oficial doc:

> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: And what happens if the link becomes invalid? Will it then help the readers?

Comment: Can you mark it as the correct answer @Nikhil and vote it up please? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

So you can do this I have done this in my application to organize contacts list. In the code "data" is the list of contacts. And then "a.last_name" is how you are accessing the last name category based on how you have your contact list object set up. Hope it helps, this will make the data object after be ordered.

```
  data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.last_name.localeCompare(b.last_name);
    })
```

Comment: I don't think there's​ "localeCompare" in Angular 2

Comment: Could you try it out because that's the process I have been using.

Comment: Yeah sure I will